# jQuery - Selector not working - Dynamic Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a function in jQuery with the intention of being able to traverse through and locate all of the required inputs for a section of a site.

```
function check_property_vars() {
    jQuery(this).parents('.property_group').find('div[id^="property_group_"]:input[required]:visible').each( function() {
        console.log('here');
    });
}
```

The problem I seem to be having is that my selector is not working. The above code should be locating each property group that I created and then targeting each input that is visible and required.

There is no error presented on click, but I can move the console.log out of the selector and it shows. The selector itself seems to be having the problem. The code itself seems to be formatted correctly since it does not break the site in any way. It simply fails silently.

https://jsfiddle.net/x0sh82uz/

I created a fiddle that contains some example code to give a better idea of how the property is presented in the code in the hopes someone can identify why my selector is not working.

Comment: Side note, you omitted jQuery in your fiddle. Also, what calls your `check_property_vars` function?

Comment: Also, what are you expecting `this` to refer to? What is invoking the function? Right now `this` is the `window` object.

Comment: Nothing is calling your javascript function, at least in the fiddle you provided.

Comment: This is invoked onClick from a button. It seemed like unnecessary fluff to add the JS for the entire form when I mentioned it was only the selector that was incorrect and all other aspects of the form and the JS itself are functional.

Comment: Why did someone -1 this? They listed it as off topic and not about programming in the close request but it is obviously about jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isolating the problem, here is the selector you are using:

```
'div[id^="property_group_"]:input[required]:visible'
```

Translated, this means:

- A `div` element...
- Whose ID begins with 'property_group_'
- Which has the 'input' pseudoclass (???)
- Which has the 'required' attribute set
- Which has the 'visible' pseudoclass

The third point there is clearly the issue, as it makes no sense.

Perhaps you meant a space instead of a `:`, as in:

```
'div[id^="property_group_"] input[required]:visible'
```

The above translates to:

- A `div` element...
- Whose ID begins with 'property_group_'
- Find a descendant `input`

  - Which has the 'required' attribute set
  - Which has the 'visible' pseudoclass

This seems more in line with what you're looking for.